# Put numbers from string into int array

Tags: c#

I have lines (string type) of numbers like "**23 78 53 4 94 32 148 31**". I need to put them into int array. Here's the lame code I wrote, but it doesn't work properly:

```
        int currentArrayValue=0;
        int currentChar=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < text1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (text1[i] != ' ')
            {
                currentChar++;
                continue;
            }

            else
            {
                for (int k = 1; k <=currentChar; k++)
                {
                    if (k == 1) Array[currentArrayValue] = text1[i - currentChar];
                    else if (k == 2) Array[currentArrayValue] = text1[i - currentChar] * 10;
                    else if (k == 3) Array[currentArrayValue] = text1[i - currentChar] * 100;
                }
                currentArrayValue++;
            }
        }
```

It can be a one-, two- or three-digit number.

Comment: `it doesn't work properly` is not a helpful description of the problem. What do you expect to get? What did you get instead? Are you getting an error/exception? If so, what is and where is it happening? *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Comment: can you not just split by spaces and then `Convert.ToInt32()` on each one. You can either use a list or just allocate a new array of length, `splitStringArray.Length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have a string as such and all the numbers are separated by spaces

```
string foo = "12 34 567 120 12";
```

All you have to do is use `string.Split(' ')` to break this string into an array then convert those values to int values.

```
int[] intArray = foo.Split(' ').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: For safety, `Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` - still works if there are extra spaces.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve what you want as the other answers point out. If you want a bit of safety checking then I'd use `TryParse`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;               
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = "1 2 3 x";
        var values = test.Split(new [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var results = new List<int>();
        foreach(var value in values)
        {
            int x;
            if(Int32.TryParse(value, out x))
            {
               results.Add(x);
            }
            else
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an integer", value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.Split` instead. You can split on each space and get an array. From there, parse each item to an int. You can actually do it all in one line with LINQ.

```
int[] myInts = text1.Split(new [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

Comment: `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` for additional safety.

Comment: @DonBoitnott good call.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "23 78 53 4 94 32 148 31";
var arr = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Downvoter, I think you'll post the reason...

Comment: Using a regular expression for something that .Split was made to do is a bit "overkill".

Comment: But it doesn't make it wrong. Just another alternative.. Also handles the case like @venerik posted, easily...

Comment: You're right, but I feel like when answering a question asked by a beginner, providing the most simple answer is the best option.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll Then people doesn' t need to upvote, but downvoting is .......

Comment: Edit your answer with an explanation and I'll change my vote ;)

Comment: @JonathanCarroll No need, we are even now....

Comment: Fair enough, but per SO guidelines, you should provide an explanation to your answer..... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Non-Linq answer

```
const string inputVal = "23 78 53 4 94 32 148 31";
string[] splitInput = inputVal.Split(' ');
int[] inputIntArray = new int[splitInput.Length];
int counter = 0;
foreach (string split in splitInput){
    inputIntArray[counter++] = int.Parse(split);
}
```